# crash error in unity using this condition even if has a limit

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, while-loop, conditional-statements

Anyone can explain me why i cant use this condition?

```
 private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.name == "healerTriger")
        Healing();
}

void Healing()
{
    takingDmg = false;
    do
    {
        hpPlayer = 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    while (hpPlayer< 50);
       

}
```

Even with if or while the condition crash unity but why ? there's a limit in there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem

```
void Healing()
{
    takingDmg = false;
    do
    {
        hpPlayer = 1 * Time.deltaTime; // this does not increate and you are staying in an infinite loop
    }
    while (hpPlayer< 50);
       

}
```

instead it should be

```
void Healing()
{
    takingDmg = false;
    do
    {
        hpPlayer += 1 * Time.deltaTime; // just put a "+" in here
    }
    while (hpPlayer< 50);
       

}
```

Comment: yep u right, i put this function in update but....update ignores the condition and does it always.... normally this must run only if hp is less 50 right ?

Comment: Yes correct. Also if my answer was helpful could you please give me a point and mark it as answer.

Comment: yes dont worry goodwill must be recognized

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as correct answer.